# how to use secrets in github actions without revealing the secret

Tags: github, github-actions

For a public repository, in github actions, assume my action runs on a compute in azure. I am confused on how i can protect the azure auth details if the CI pipeline has to run in azure.

Lets say to use this action, i have to use a secret and i set an environment variable's value to be the secret - have I not lost the point of having a secret? A malicious user can send a PR that prints the value of the environment variable :

```
user_password: {{secret.USER_PASSWORD}}
```

User code:

```
print(os.environment['user_password'])
```

The malicious user does not have to guess since the workflow is public and he knows which env var has the secret.

Where am i wrong?

Comment: Aren't secrets redacted when you print them?

Comment: how is it enforced? once its an environment variable things should just work like they do with other environemnt variables. or am i missing something?

Comment: I can only find it mentioned [here](https://bounty.github.com/targets/github-actions.html), and in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets#limits-for-secrets), they show a way to fetch large secrets which then are *not* redacted. Looks like it might be doing string matching? Have you tried with a dummy secret?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62142092/is-it-okay-to-use-github-secrets-with-a-public-repo/62143130#62143130) covers some points to note about using secrets in a public repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitHub, like other CI providers, redacts most secrets from the logs.  It considers a variety of formats and tries to scrub them.  However, in general, you should be careful to avoid printing them to the logs because no system is foolproof and not every possible encoding can be considered.

If you're worried about forked repositories trying to access your secrets, [they can't](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets#using-encrypted-secrets-in-a-workflow); that's specifically not allowed for the reason you describe.  So if someone opens a PR against your repository, they won't be able to access the secrets unless the branch is in your repository (in which case, don't grant that person write access to your repo).  It's presumed that you'll perform basic code review to catch any malicious code before merging, so a bad actor won't be able to run any code with the secrets for your repository.

In general, though, using environment variables as a way to pass secrets to programs is a best practice, assuming the running system and programs are trusted.  Other users on the system cannot see the environment, and in a CI system the system and programs are assumed to be trusted.

Comment: Won't u run the CI on the PR to see whether the workflow does not fail.Why would you wait until the PR gets merged to run your github action workflow?

Comment: Yes, you do run CI on the PR.  However, those don't use the main repository's secrets.  Usually CI does not require secrets, while things like deployment may, so this is nor a problem.

Comment: so ive seen a bunch of actions: run on pull_request, push. Both of these run on PR. How do i make sure that this action only runs when either it is the master branch or the admin runs it manually?

Comment: That's a separate question and should be answered separately.  Because this is a comment I can't include suitably formatted YAML that explains how to do that.