# Is it possible to change action's version in github marketplace?

Tags: security, versioning, github-actions

Given that action's versions derive from their repo's tags.
Can one change an already published version by moving the tag to another commit?

If so, it's a serious security problem.. but I can't find any source to reassure me.

Anyway, it is always possible to use commit id instead of version:)

Comment: If you are passing secrets to third party actions there are some points to consider and recommendations in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62143130/11934042).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. When a tag is moved to point to a different commit, the corresponding release becomes a draft and it disappears from the Marketplace, but it can be published again.

Notice that an action doesn't need to be published on the marketplace to be used anyway.

Moving tags is actually the [official recommendation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/about-custom-actions#using-release-management-for-actions) for major versions and it has been [debated](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/214); that discussion mentions that versioning will improve when moving to using the GitHub Package Registry for Actions, but that hasn't happened yet and the [GitHub roadmap](https://github.com/github/roadmap/projects/1?card_filter_query=label%3Aactions) doesn't mention it, as far as I can tell.